# Tests fail to run after upgrading .net core from 2.1 to 3.1

Tags: c#, testing, .net-core

Tests fail to run after upgrading .net core from 2.1 to 3.1. Main error:

`vstest.console process failed to connect to testhost process after 90 seconds. This may occur due to machine slowness, please set environment variable VSTEST_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT to increase timeout.`

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous fixes out there that didn't work for me. The fix that worked was adding the package: `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`